# Creating Form Control at Cell Location with VBA in Excel

Tags: forms, excel, vba, cell

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725754/accessing-event-procedures-of-form-controls-with-vba-in-excel)

I am using `ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add()` to add format control buttons to a worksheet. This method suffers when I have to add several buttons with a certain horizontal distance between them and column widths change, causing a slight drift between buttons.

I would like to instead use a cell reference which would prevent this drifting caused by column width changes.

Comment: Cells have `.Top` and `.Left` properties which you can use to position objects over (or relative to) them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add BUTTON_LEFT, BUTTON_TOP, _
BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT
```

This will create a button at the active cell. Change as possible.

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add ActiveCell.Left, ActiveCell.Top, _
ActiveCell.Width, ActiveCell.Height
```

**EDIT**: Beaten by Tim!